# Tool to determine if any HTTP bookmarks can be replaced with HTTPS equivalents (Firefox)

Tags: security, firefox, privacy, bookmark, http

Can anyone recommend a software tool that will go through all bookmarks stored in the Firefox web browser and determine if any **HTTP** bookmarks can be replaced with **HTTPS** equivalents?

The software can be a Firefox extension, a separate tool (for Windows), or even a web-app.  It can automatically change the qualifying bookmarks, or just provide a list of which ones can be manually changed.

It can have a GUI, or be a command-line tool.

Recommendations can be for gratis (free of charge) or commercial software.

Answer (score 2):

[HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere)

- is a Firefox plugin
- is free
- changes called URLS **on the fly** from HTTP to HTTPS if possible

It does not convert the bookmarks - but as long as you don't want to export your bookmarks to another browser, it works fine.

IMHO, the plugin has become quite popular since the [Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) initiative.

Comment: If you think this is totally inappropriate, drop a comment and I'll delete the answer (and then perhaps state that you have tried HTTPS Everywhere and it does not fit)

Comment: It's a work-around similar to what I currently use (alternative: [Smart HTTPS](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/smart-https)). As I didn't see any such addon doing exactly what OP asked for, this is better than nothing ;)

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  It's not what I want, but it's definitely not inappropriate, so I say leave your quality answer, as it might help someone.  It's a well known quality extension, but from examining the code, it appears to rely on a static list of sites.  Consequently, I think it only works on sites in its list.  The *Smart HTTPS* extension recommended by Izzy doesn't have that limitation, but likely slows things down because it has to check for HTTPS support for every site each time it is loaded.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Not slow. But having tried it for ~48h, I found it a bit unreliable. E.g. it never switched to https on SE sites, no idea why.

Comment: @Izzy I wonder why it isn't slow... truly checking to see if a site supports HTTPS (properly) is a slow process.  For example, it has to determine if the HTTPS server is just slow to respond or does not exist.  Maybe it just does a quick cursory check; I haven't tried that extension, nor had a chance to examine the code.

Comment: That fits my experience with it: it seems to check for a split-second, but give up quite fast. Works for some sites, but not for all. UX first (user shouldn't feel it's slow). Funny thing is: you can set a site to be forced to https – but that didn't work for me if I just put the *site* in. It however worked when putting the entire URL. Defeats the purpose somehow: should do when entering the main page via the address bar always, but not when following links. // But we drift into OT, this is not a forum, @RockPaperLizard :)